# Replace img src and class

Tags: regex

I want to change all `img`s in the content. I do so by using RegEx.

**RegEx**:

```
/<img src="([^\"]+)" class="([^\"]+)"/ig
```

**Content**:

```
<img src="test.jpg" class="qr" />

<img src="test2.jpg" width="230" height="130" class="qr" />

<img src="test3.jpg" style="width:705px" />
```

This is my problem: the regular expression only matches one time (the first line). But I want to change *all* `src` and `class` attributes.

You can verify this here: http://regexr.com/3asul.

Comment: What language are you using? Most languages have a replaceAll functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second case has some other attributes within it. You can use `.*?` inbetween to match that as well:

```
/<img src=".*?".*? class=".*?"/gi
```

`.*?` means any character, at least 0 times, as little as possible.

If you want to replace any `img` with an `src` and with an *optional* `class` you can wrap the `class` part in a non-capturing group and use the `?` quantifier and then you’d have to add another `>` to force the RegEx to go to the end of the tag:

```
/<img src=".*?".*?(?: class=".*?")?>/gi
```